# Quartus: Error (12004): Port z does not exist in primitive x of instance y

Tags: verilog, flipflop, error, quartus

I cannot find any source for this error, any help much appreciated!

Error: `Error (12004): Port "a" does not exist in primitive "tff" of instance "t1"`

```
module part1(SW);
  input [0:9] SW;
  wire q1;

  tff t1(.t(SW[2]), .clk(KEY[0]), .a(SW[1]), .q(q1));

endmodule

module tff(t, clk, a, q);

  input t;
  input clk;
  input a;

  output reg q;
  always@(posedge clk)
    begin
        if(a)
            q <= 1;
        else
            q <= 0;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use sensible names for your modules, not really shortened ones.

[`tff`](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.1/mergedProjects/hdl/prim/prim_file_tff.htm) is a primitive supplied with Quartus, so it is using the built in **primitive**, not your **module**. The primitive doesn't have a port named `a`, so you get an error.

The error message is quite specific about this. It tells you that the "primitive" doesn't have that port. If it was an issue with your module it would tell you the "module" doesn't have that port.